# How to split script and option at space, if script path can contain escaped spaces?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A script is located in **"just a dir/my script.sh"**, 
and a call to this script is:

```
path_options = 'just\ a\ dir/my\ script.sh --option'
```

How to split the `path_options` into the below?:

```
['just a dir/my script.sh', '--option']
```

OK, @Kasra gave an answer for the above example, but what if there may be multiple options like?:

```
path_options = 'just\ a\ dir/my\ script.sh --option --option2 ... --optionN'
```

Ended up doing:

```
a = re.split(r'[^\\] ', path_options, maxsplit=1)  # Split at first space that is not '\ '
a = [re.sub(r'\\ ', ' ', a[0])] + a[1:]  # Convert all '\ ' in first element to ' '
```

gives:

> ['just a dir/my script.s', '--option .. --optionN']

As per @JoelCornett comment:

```
a = shlex.split(path_options)
```

gives:

> ['^/just a dir/my script.sh', '--option', '..', '--optionN']

Comment: Use shlex.split. That's what that module is for. Shlex will also properly handle posix shell quoting.

Comment: @JoelCornett: Thanks, it was something like that I was after, instead of just cooking something for the few example I can come up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.split` to split your path with `\` or space then slice and join :

```
>>> l=re.split(r'[\\ ]+',path_options)
>>> l=[' '.join(l[:-1]),l[-1]]
>>> l
['just a dir/my script.sh', '--option']
```